# Azure Custom Owner Role

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I am trying to create an Azure custom owner role, where I give certain access. I will assign this role to a RBAC group and add users to that group. However how do I make it so that this role can only assign this specific role and only see this role.

Comment: so people who have this role can only assign the same role to people in a specific group ? Not sure to understand what you are trying to do, could you explain a little bit more please ?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks so much for replying. So the idea is to create a custom owner role, this custom role will have limitations. I will have to create a RBAC group with let's say 10 users and apply this role to that group.  This custom owner role should only be able to assign and see this custom owner role and no other role. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: so you mean members of this custom owner role can only assign other users to this custom role ?

Comment: @Thomas yes correct

Comment: You could just make them onwer of the group so they can add/delete other people to the group ?